# perl bitwise AND and bitwise shifting

Tags: perl, bit-manipulation, libpcap

I was reading some example code snippet for the module [`Net::Pcap::Easy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Net-Pcap-Easy/Easy.pod), and I came across this piece of code

```
my $l3protlen = ord substr $raw_bytes, 14, 1;
my $l3prot = $l3protlen & 0xf0 >> 2;    # the protocol part
return unless $l3prot == 4;    # return unless IPv4
my $l4prot = ord substr $packet, 23, 1;
return unless $l4prot == '7';
```

After doing a total hex dump of the raw packet $raw_bytes, I can see that this is an ethernet frame, and not on a TCP/UDP packet. Can someone please explain what the above code does?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For parsing the frame, I looked up [this page](http://nerdcrunch.com/2011/05/09/how-to-decode-ethernet-frames/).

Now onto the Perl...

```
my $l3protlen =  ord substr $raw_bytes, 14, 1;
```

Extract the 15th byte (character) from `$raw_bytes`, and convert to its ordinal value (e.g. a character 'A' would be converted to an integer 65 (0x41), assuming the character set is ASCII). This is how Perl can handle binary data as if it were a string (e.g. passing it to `substr`) but then let you get the binary values back out and handle them as numbers. (But remember [TMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).)

In the IPv4 frame, the first 14 bytes are the MAC header (6 bytes each for destination and source MAC address, followed by 2-byte Ethertype which was probably 0x8000 - you could have checked this). Following this, the 15th byte is the start of the Ethernet data payload: the first byte of this contains Version (upper 4 bytes) and Header Length in DWORDs (lower 4 bytes).

Now it looks to me like there is a bug in the next line of this sample code, but it may well normally work by a fluke!

```
my $l3prot    = $l3protlen & 0xf0 >> 2; # the protocol part
```

In Perl, `>>` has higher precedence than `&`, so this will be equivalent to

```
my $l3prot    = $l3protlen & (0xf0 >> 2);
```

or if you prefer

```
my $l3prot    = $l3protlen & 0x3c;
```

So this extracts bits 2 - 5 from the `$l3prot` value: the mask value 0x3c is 0011 1100 in binary. So for example a value of 0x86 (in binary, 1000 0110) would become 0x04 (binary 0000 0100).
In fact a 'normal' IPv4 value is 0x45, i.e. protocol type 4, header length 5 dwords. Mask that with 0x3c and you get... 4! But only by fluke: you have tested the top 2 bits of the length, not the protocol type!

This line should surely be

```
my $l3prot = ($l3protlen & 0xf0) >> 4;
```

(note brackets for precedence and a shift of 4 bits, not 2). (I found this same mistake in the [CPAN documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Net-Pcap-Easy-1.4207/Easy.pod) so I guess it's probably quite widely spread.)

```
return unless $l3prot == 4; # return unless IPv4
```

For IPv4 we expect this value to be 4 - if it isn't, jump out of the function right away. (So the wrong code above gives the result which lets this be interpreted as an IPv4 packet, but only by luck.)

```
my $l4prot = ord substr $packet, 23, 1;
```

Now extract the 24th byte and convert to ordinal value in the same way. This is the Protocol byte from the IP header:

```
return unless $l4prot == '7';
```

We expect this to be 7 - if it isn't jump out of the function right away. (According to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml), 7 is "Core-based trees"... but I guess you know which protocols you are interested in!)

Comment: Very well explained. Yes, I was looking specifically for udp, so 7.

Comment: @nohup - Thanks! but UDP is 17, not 7...  Also have you tried this with my suggested correction to the "`& 0xf0`" line?

Comment: Excellent and well explained. Good job spotting those mistakes

Comment: Yes. I referred to the link that you provided, and can see
`17 UDP User Datagram  [RFC768][Jon_Postel]`.
And yes, I wanted to understand what am I doing before blindly copying from the cpan documentation, and is using `my $l3prot = ($l3protlen & 0xf0) >> 4;`. Thank you very much for helping me understand this and spotting out the mistakes.

Comment: @nohup - Thanks, glad to have been able to help! What seemed like a simple Perl question turned out to be very interesting (more interesting than the work I was supposed to be doing! <g>).